# Exit from for function after detecting obstacles

Tags: loop

```
#include <HCSR04.h>

int red = 13;
int green = 12;
int blue = 11;
int trigger = 9;
int echo = 8;
int halt;

void setup(){
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(trigger, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void redLed(){
  rgb(255,0,0);
  delay(200);
}

void rgb(int r, int g, int b){
  analogWrite(red, r);
  analogWrite(green, g);
  analogWrite(blue, b);
}

void fadeBlu(){
  
    for (int i=0; i<=255; i+=5){
    rgb(0,0,i);
    delay(40);

    Serial.print("halt in IF is ");
    Serial.println(halt);
    }
    
    for(int i=255; i>=0; i-=5) {
      rgb(0,0,i);
      delay(40);

      Serial.print("halt ELSE is ");
      Serial.println(halt);
    } 
}

void human() {
  
  UltraSonicDistanceSensor distanceSensor(trigger, echo);
  double distance = distanceSensor.measureDistanceCm();
  halt = 0;

  // cover sensor
  if (distance<=30) {
    halt=0;
    redLed();
  }
  // no cover
    halt=-1;
    fadeBlu();
}

void loop(){
  human();
}
```

I'm looking for a way to exit from "for" loop of fadeBlue() function if the hand is detected in front of sensor. I would like that in any case of fading and if there is hand in front of sensor the led became red. In my code the led doesn't stay red if I had hand in front of the sensor and also the value of "halt" doesn't change. I put some serial.println to make debugging.

Comment: Did you try to [`break`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/break/) out of the loop?

Comment: No, i don't know how to use break here.. i have to break in for?

Comment: `if( [some-condition] ) return;`

Comment: Alternatively, calculate the brightness the blue led should be, based on time (`millis()`). E.g. `rgb(0,0,(millis()/40)%256);`

Comment: I don't understand how to use millis there..

Answer (score 0):

First, try to avoid duplication of code, so make a sub function (I slightly changed the print statement, but I assume it's only for debugging):

```
void fadeBlu()
{
    fadeBlueCycle(0, 255, 5);
    fadeBlueCycle(255, 0, -5);
}

void fadeBlueCycle(uint8_t start, uint8_t end, int8_t step)
{
    for (int i = start; i != end; i += step)
    {
        rgb(0, 0, i);
        delay(40);

        Serial.print("halt in step ");
        Serial.print(step);
        Serial.println(halt);
    }
}
```

Now to break from the `for`, you can use `break`, or simply `return`. It's not a good practice to have multiple `return` statements in one function, thus put it at the end, and use a `break`. Also, some people don't like a `break` and prefer using a `while. This would look like:

```
void fadeBlueCycle(uint8_t start, uint8_t end, int8_t step)
{
    uint8_t i = start;
    bool condition = true;

    while ((i != end) && condition) // or !condition, depending on what you prefer
    {
        rgb(0, 0, i);
        delay(40);

        Serial.print("halt in step ");
        Serial.print(step);
        Serial.println(halt);

        condition = `some condition`;
        i += step;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer as usual. Note that the for loop in C/C++ allows you to add additional checks, so you could also write the for loop as `for (int i = start; i < end && condition; i += step)` and get the same effect as the while loop, while also having the for loop manage the counter.

Comment: @DuncanC True ... and personally I don't like this concept, as it's like a `while` loop, written as a `for` loop. But it's personal. I have seen many professional projects using it this way (with the `for`). Personally I consider a `for` loop like an unconditional loop where beforehand the number of iterations is known, and a `while` loop as a conditional loop, where the number of iterations is not known beforehand. The `break` statement is kind of discussable in this sense. (But everything is better than a `goto`).

Comment: The condition of the while in my case should be if there is obstacles in front of sensor?

Comment: That depends on what your requirements are. If you want to break the loop based on some condition, use the condition you need. The `while` loop will stop when  `condition` is true, or you can use the not (!) operator (thus `!condition) to stop the `while` loop when the condition is false.

Comment: I noticed that the break happens ONLY after the end of the while loop and not at any time when there is obstacle in front of sensor, why this happens?

Comment: Assign the  condition you implemented to the variable `condition` and print it... It should change according to what you implemented.

Comment: No, i can't understand what kind of condition i need there. The only condition that stop the while loop should be something related to the distance from the sensor, (distance<=30) but i have used that on human() function...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109490/discussion-between-tommy-and-michel-keijzers).